# Codeigniter - Url to style.css and media files are correct but nothing is displayed

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, codeigniter-url

I've got a huge problem with my codeigniter.
I just moved the codeigniter files to another domain. I've already changed the base_url and the style.css and other media files are implemented with base_url + path_to_the_media_folder.
The path is right, but codeigniter doesn't find my media folder where everything is in. On the other domain this worked totally fine.

Maybe this helps solving the problem:
The folder in which I have the media and css files is located in the same directory as CIs "application", "media", "system", etc. folders.

How can I solve this problem?

Best regards
Paul

Comment: Have you checked the network panel ? Do you see any 4** error for the medias you're trying to load ?

Comment: Hello, I've checked that already but everything seem to work fine. I've also tried reuploading the files again and again but no change at all.

Comment: have you checked for your file permission?

Comment: Yep, file permissions are the same as on the other domain where it works fine.

Comment: @Vinie any other ideas what does comes from and how to solve it?

Comment: i can't figure it out without seeing your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update: Problem solved**
Found out that it was only because I forgot to change the .htaccess (because my new domain had a https connection and the old one not).
Thanks anyone for help.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any error you are getting? Please share the error

try below  URL

```
http://your domain name/your folder name/index.php/
```

Comment: I always get an 404 Error because it could find the folder, even when it's there and the url is right.

Answer (score 0):

```
There is two chance to get the 404 error
 1) your path is wrong.  2) There is issue on file name or class name.

Controller class names should be all lowercase, and Controller file name should be Uppercase.

like your class name is  
class example extends CI_Controller 

and file name is 

Example.php
```

Comment: I'm sorry but both options you posted are not valid. 1) path is not wrong (already checked that several times) and 2) it's not a class and the file name is correct. When I change the base_url back to the old domain and load the same files on the old domain it works fine.

Comment: If posible please share the new domain and old domain url

Comment: For security issues I'm unfortunately not able to post the urls at this moment.